# confused whether the training is going well or not?

Tags: python, generative-adversarial-network

I am doing grayscale image colorization using DCGAN, I don't know how my algorithm is trained I have one figure which is captured at 42 epoch.[This is the image captured at 40 epoch](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OUUBe.png)

Comment: Normally you would have a test dataset and another to validate, one against which you would test the training is improving and the other to test between different parameterizations of the model and that's how you know

Comment: can you explain the figure

Answer (score 0):

With most other Neural Networks you can tell by the loss function and how the training and validation sets converge(or fail to converge). In GANs however, there isn't really an objective way to tell how the GAN is performing through its loss functions alone(although Discriminator loss steadily decreasing is a good sign) as the Generator and Discriminator counterbalance each other: that is, the Generator tries to fool the Discriminator and failure to do so results in penalization while the Discriminator's inability to tell fake from real images results in penalization. However, there are various other quantitative and qualitative tells.

With reference to the graph in your question, the loss spikes up for the discriminator when the generator manages to fool the discriminator(penalization) while slightly decreasing in the generator. As one can see the spikes in the Discriminator become less dramatic as the Discriminator steadily gets better at telling fakes from real.

Reference [this](https://machinelearningmastery.com/how-to-evaluate-generative-adversarial-networks/).